# IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'README.rst'

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, django-comments

I tried to use pip to install django_comments, then this error occurred(run in virtualenv @Windows):
traceback:

```
(env) E:\mdknowledge>pip install django-comments
Collecting django-comments
  Using cached django-comments-1.0.0.b.tar.bz2
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
      File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-pi1rwb\django-comments\setup.py", line 18, in <module> long_description = open('README.rst').read(),
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'README.rst'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\dell\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-pi1rwb\django-comments
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this question by downgrade my django-contrib-comments module version from 1.6 to 1.5 using:

```
pip uninstall django-contrib-comments
pip install django-contrib-comments==1.5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can install this package directly from the github with this command:

```
$ pip install -e git+https://github.com/marazmiki/django-comments.git#egg=django-comments
```